# Correct use of 'whatsoever'

Tags: word-usage, pronouns

Which is the correct usage: 'for whatsoever reason' or 'for any reason whatsoever'?

Example (taken from [here](https://ludwig.guru/s/for+any+reason+whatsoever)):

> A governor may give a pardon or commute a sentence any day of the week, for any reason **whatsoever**.

Comment: You should include a full sentence for context.

Comment: @KillingTime well i'm not sure that 'for whatsoever reason' is correct so i can't provide a sentence for this specific use. my guess would be that, if correct, its use would be the same as for 'for any reason whatsoever'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word *whatsoever* is a synonym for the phrase *at all* in these sentences. The following two formulations are equivalent:

> The governor may issue pardons for any reason *whatsoever*.

> The governor may issue pardons for any reason *at all*.

The meaning indicated is that there is no restriction on what the governor may do. The words *whatsoever* and *at all* both intensify the word *any*.

Note that *whatsoever* is NOT a synonym of *whatever* in this context, as the word *whatever* cannot be used in the sentence above. However, in an archaic mode one may use *whatsoever* as a synonym of *whatever* when the word is being used as a pronoun:

> Whatever you do, don't fall down.

> Whatsoever thou doest, fall not down.